# is possible dynamic cast left operands in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a legacy code support issue, so I'm trying to cast something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int a;
  long b;
  float c;
}tag_legacy;

typedef struct
{
  int aa;
  int a;
  long b;
  float c;
}tag_new_device;

bool isNewDevice;
char RxData[100];

int getMemberA(void)
{
  //get member a value
  if (isNewDevice)
  {
    return (( tag_new_device * ) RxData )->a;
  }
  else
  {
    return (( tag_legacy * ) RxData )->a;
  }
}
```

it's works.
but, this is just example.
actual source code has many member and related code...
and this way It will reduce readability and make source lines unnecessarily long.

```
#define getType(VAR)     (isNewDevice ? (( tag_new_device * ) RxData ) : (( tag_legacy * ) RxData ))

int getMemberA(void)
{
  return getType(RxData)->a; //error
}
```

Of course, a syntax error occurs, and looking back, I think I was thinking of a nonsensical code. I just want to explain my intentions and see if there is another efficient way.

[add]
Originally, I was writing in C, and I am trying to build in C++ language to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: What is C/C++? Is it some kind of Java/JavaScript?

Comment: You should parse the `RxData` and extract individual values from it and assign them to the required structure member.

Comment: sorry it is c++

Comment: You could solve it with a function template if isNewDevice is constexpr. So, you should post a [mcve].

Comment: In C++, do not use macros as functions. Use template functions instead.

Comment: What is bad in encapsulating the gory details in one single function, and then use it everywhere?

Comment: Also, I would steonglyyadvixe you to write proper deserialization, instead of

Comment: Sorry for the confusion by not clarifying the language.
Originally, I was writing in C, and I am trying to build in C++ language to solve this problem.

Comment: @Tweleve_Monkeys What exactly is `isNewDevice`? Is it a compile time constant?

Comment: @Jason Liam 'isNewDevice' it is runtime variable not a constant

Comment: Avoid using the phrase "dynamic cast" if you are not talking about the C++ keyword `dynamic_cast`. It has specific properties that are not relevant (or appropriate) here at all. In your example, you are effectively performing `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: If you were to move `aa` to the end of the structure, you could then simply cast to either type to extract `a` since in the this case the structures match type wise.

Comment: don't do `typedef struct` in C++. `struct` is already a first class object in C++, so doing `typedef` on it is useless and pollutes the namespace

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::visit` (with a function returning `std::variant<tag_new_device *, tag_legacy *>`), or make a similar function of your own:

```
template <typename F>
decltype(auto) VisitDevice(F &&func)
{
    if (isNewDevice)
        return std::forward<F>(func)(*reinterpret_cast<tag_new_device *>(RxData));
    else
        return std::forward<F>(func)(*reinterpret_cast<legacy_device *>(RxData));
}
```

Then you can get a member (with the same name in both structs) using `VisitDevice([](auto &dev){return dev.a;})`.

If the members are named differently, or you just need different behavior for two devices, the classical `overloaded{...}` template might help (see [example for `std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)).